# accessing xtime variable Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am implementing system call that will return the current time of the day (for learning purpose).
I have looked at implementations of gettimeofday() on Linux 3.19.2
from the books I checked I got that 
The current time of day (the wall time) is defined in kernel/time/timekeeping.c:

```
struct timespec xtime;
```

[Linux kernel development Rober Love]

however I couldn't able to get the xtime variable definition in that file.

**where is the xtime variable declared in the Linux kernel and how can I access it from my module or my function?**
**what are the headers I should  include?**

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 6):

That reference is obsolete. Recent kernels no longer have `xtime`. Though there are still some fields in the kernel timekeeping structure with a prefix of `xtime_` that I assume are descended from it. See, for example, `struct timekeeper` in `include/linux/timekeeper_internal.h`.

You would probably want to stick to the slightly more stable functions defined in `include/linux/timekeeping.h`

Comment: you are right I $grep -lar "struct timespec xtime;"  * and couldn't find any

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. You can call `do_gettimeofday` or `getnstimeofday64` or `ktime_get`, all of which will you give you some version of the kernel time.